# There is a problem in making multiple select boxes with react and type scripts

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I just made a multi-select box. Selecting one of the upper categories changes the lower category and table. I have made changes, but they should not be changed immediately, but should be modified to change when the search button is pressed. I'm attaching the code below. I wonder where to add the code. Please Help me. ....

```
import ~

const cx = className.bind(style);

const TableCard = styled(Card)`
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;

  table {
    border-radius: 6px;

    tr {
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
  }
`;

export default function ManageLog() {
    const [userInfo] = useUserInfo();

    const [userInfoLog, setUserInfoLog] = useState({
        name: "User Info",
        userSeq: 0
    });

    const [memberType, setMemberType] = useState({ 
        name: "Member Type", 
        memberSeq: 0
    });

    const [connectType, setConnectType] = useState({
        name: "Connect Type",
        connectSeq: 0
    });

    const [errorLog, setErrorLog] = useState({
        name: "Error Log",
        errorSeq: 0
    });
    
    const userInfoLogDefaultValue = useMemo(() => {
        return {
          name: "User Info",
          userSeq: 0
        };
      }, []);

      const memberTypeDefaultValue = useMemo(() => {
        return {
          name: "Member Type",
          memberSeq: 0
        };
      }, [userInfoLog.userSeq]);

      const connectTypeDefaultValue = useMemo(() => {
        return {
          name: "Connect Type",
          connectSeq: 0
        };
      }, [userInfoLog.userSeq]);

      const errorLogDefaultValue = useMemo(() => {
          return {
              name: "Error Log",
              errorSeq: 0
          };
      }, [userInfoLog.userSeq]);

    const col: ICol[] = [
        {
            title: "NO",
            dataIndex: 'no',
            width: "80px"
        },{
            title: "User ID",
            dataIndex: 'userId'
        },{
            title: "Member Type",
            dataIndex: 'memberType'
        },{
            title: "Company Name",
            dataIndex: 'companyName'
        },{
            title: "Change Type",
            dataIndex: 'changeForm',
            width: "148px"
        },{
            title: "Change Time",
            dataIndex: 'changeTime'
        }
    ];

    const loginCol: ICol[] = [
        {
            width: "80px",
            title: "NO",
            dataIndex: "no"
        }, {
            title: "User ID",
            dataIndex: "userId"
        }, {
            title: "Company Name",
            dataIndex: "companyName"
        }, {
            title: "IP Address",
            dataIndex: "ipAddress"
        }, {
            title: "Connect Time",
            dataIndex: "connectTime"
        }, {
            title: "Connect Type",
            dataIndex: "connectType",
            render: value => {
            if (value === "Login")
                return <span className={cx('loginText')}>{"Login"}</span>;
            else if (value === "Logout")
                return <span className={cx('logoutText')}>{"Logout"}</span>;
            else if (value === "LoginFail")
                return <span className={cx('loginFail')}>{"LoginFail"}</span>;
            else if (value === "session")
                return <span className={cx('sessionText')}>{"session"}</span>;
            else
                return
        }
        }
    ];

    const errorCol: ICol[] = [
        {
            width: "80px",
            title: "NO",
            dataIndex: "no"
        }, {
            title: "Error Time",
            dataIndex: "errorTime"
        }, {
            title: "Error Page",
            dataIndex: "errorPage"
        }, {
            title: "Error Type",
            dataIndex: "errorType"
        }
    ];

    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
    const [filterDate, setFilterDate] = useState([new Date(), new Date()]);
    const [searchOptions, setSearchOptions] = useState(null);
    const { isLoading, list, pagination } = useCondDate(searchOptions);
    const { page, setPage, setSize, total } = pagination;

    const handleSearchData = () => {
        console.log(userInfoLog, memberType, connectType, errorLog, filterDate, searchValue)
        setSearchOptions({
            userInfoLog: userInfoLog.userSeq,
            memberType: memberType.memberSeq,
            connectType: connectType.connectSeq,
            errorKind: errorLog.errorSeq,
            startDate: dateFormat(filterDate[0], "yyyy.MM.dd  HH:mm:ss"),
            endDate: dateFormat(filterDate[1], "yyyy.MM.dd  HH:mm:ss")
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Row justifyContent="flex-start">
                {(userInfo?.type === "aggregator_member" || userInfo?.type === "aggregator") &&
                <Col width={180} mr={10}>
                    <Select   
                        onSelect={v => setUserInfoLog(v)}
                        options={[
                            { name: "User Info", userSeq: 0},
                            { name: "Login Log", userSeq: 1},
                            { name: "Error Log", userSeq: 2}
                        ]}
                        defaultValue={userInfoLogDefaultValue}
                        selectKey="userSeq"
                        labelKey='name'                 
                    /> 
                </Col>
                } 

                <Col width={105} mr={10}>
                    {userInfoLog.userSeq === 0 ?
                    <>
                    <Select
                        onSelect={v => setMemberType(v)}
                        options={[
                            { name: "Member Type", memberSeq: 0},
                            { name: "Member", memberSeq: 1},
                            { name: "Manager", memberSeq: 2}
                        ]}
                        defaultValue={memberTypeDefaultValue}
                        selectKey="memberSeq"
                        labelKey='name'     
                    />
                    </>: null}

                    {userInfoLog.userSeq ===  1 ?
                    <>
                        <Select
                        onSelect={v => setConnectType(v)}
                        options={[
                            { name: "User ID", connectSeq: 0},
                            { name: "Connect Time", connectSeq: 1},
                            { name: "Connect Type", connectSeq: 2}
                        ]}
                        defaultValue={connectTypeDefaultValue}
                        selectKey="connectSeq"
                        labelKey='name'
                    /> 
                    </> : null}  

                    {userInfoLog.userSeq === 2 ?
                    <>
                        <Select 
                        onSelect={v => setErrorLog(v)}
                        options={[
                            { name: "Error Type", errorSeq: 0},
                            { name: "404", errorSeq: 1},
                            { name: "500", errorSeq: 2}
                        ]}
                        defaultValue={errorLogDefaultValue}
                        selectKey="errorSeq"
                        labelKey='name'
                        />
                    </> : null}
                </Col>

                <Col width={333} mr={10}>
                    <DatePicker onChangeDate={date => setFilterDate(date as [Date, Date])} 
                    disabled={false}
                    isRange={true}
                    format={"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"} />
                </Col>
                <Col width={150} mr={5}>
                    <BorderedMiniInput
                        value={searchValue}
                        onChange={setSearchValue}
                        placeholder=" ID"
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Button
                        primary={true}
                        label={""}
                        size="large"
                        icon={"icon_input_search2"}
                        iconSize={18}
                        bgColor={"#98A3C7"}
                        hoverColor={"#C7C7E8"}
                        onClick={() => handleSearchData()}
                    />
                </Col>
                <Col style={{marginLeft: 'auto'}}>
                    <Button
                        label={"excel"}
                        size="large"
                        icon={"icon_xls"}
                        iconSize={18}
                        bgColor={'#fff'}
                        borderColor={"#24D0AF"}
                    />
                </Col>
                </Row>
                {!isLoading && <>
                    {userInfoLog.userSeq === 0 ?
                    <>
                        <Row>
                            <Col width={'100%'}>
                                <TableCard>
                                    <Table 
                                    data={[
                                        {
                                            no : 1,
                                            userId : "admin001",
                                            memberType : "ann",
                                            companyName : "ann",
                                            changeForm : "ann",
                                            changeTime : "2021.11.06 17:30:00"
                                        },{
                                            no : 2,
                                            userId : "admin002",
                                            memberType : "ann",
                                            companyName : "ann",
                                            changeForm : "ann",
                                            changeTime : "2021.01.06 17:30:00"
                                        },{
                                            no : 3,
                                            userId : "admin003",
                                            memberType : "ann",
                                            companyName : "ann(ann,
                                            changeForm : "ann",
                                            changeTime : "2021.01.31 17:30:00"
                                        },{
                                            no : 4,
                                            userId : "admin004",
                                            memberType : "ann",
                                            companyName : "ann)",
                                            changeForm : "ann",
                                            changeTime : "2021.02.06 17:30:00"
                                        },{
                                            no : 5,
                                            userId : "admin005",
                                            memberType : "ann",
                                            companyName : "ann",
                                            changeForm : "ann",
                                            changeTime : "2021.02.09 17:30:00"
                                        }
                                    ]} 
                                    col={col} 
                                    keyItem="no" 
                                    pagination />
                                </TableCard>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </> 
                    : null }
                    
                    {userInfoLog.userSeq === 1 ?
                    <>
                        <Row>
                            <Col width={'100%'}>
                            <TableCard>
                                    <Table 
                                    data={[
                                        {
                                            no : 1,
                                            userId : "admin001",
                                            companyName : "ann",
                                            ipAddress : "123.12.1.0",
                                            connectType : "ann",
                                            connectTime : "2021.11.06 17:30:00"
                                        }
                                    ]} 
                                    col={loginCol} 
                                    keyItem="no" 
                                    onPageChange={(page, perPage) => {
                                    setPage(page - 1);
                                    setSize(perPage);
                                    }
                                }
                                totalCount={total}
                                />
                            </TableCard>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </> : null}

                    {userInfoLog.userSeq === 2 ?
                    <>
                        <Row>
                            <Col width={"100%"}>
                                <TableCard>
                                    <Table 
                                        data={[
                                            {
                                                no : 1,
                                                errorTime : "2022.01.31 17:30:00",
                                                errorPage : "http://localhost8081/order/ordPwTrdList.do",
                                                errorType : "500"
                                            }, {
                                                no : 2,
                                                errorTime : "2022.02.06 17:30:00",
                                                errorPage : "http://localhost8081/order/ordPwTrdList.do",
                                                errorType : "404"
                                            }, {
                                                no : 3,
                                                errorTime : "2022.02.11 17:30:00",
                                                errorPage : "http://localhost8081/order/ordPwTrdList.do",
                                                errorType : "500"
                                            }, {
                                                no : 4,
                                                errorTime : "2022.02.13 17:30:00",
                                                errorPage : "http://localhost8081/order/ordPwTrdList.do",
                                                errorType : "500"
                                            }, {
                                                no : 5,
                                                errorTime : "2022.02.14 17:30:00",
                                                errorPage : "http://localhost8081/order/ordPwTrdList.do",
                                                errorType : "404"
                                            }
                                        ]}
                                        col={errorCol}
                                        keyItem="no"
                                        onPageChange={(page, perPage) => {
                                            setPage(page - 1);
                                            setSize(perPage);
                                        }}
                                        totalCount={total}
                                    />
                                </TableCard>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </> : null}
                </>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your code is a big ball and not easily understandable for others (it takes time..). Please edit the question and create a `minimal-reproducible-example`. If you are stuck in coding it often helps to isolate the problem and setup a sandbox. In a sandbox you can focus on the  essentials and will less likely be confused by irrelevant stuff. 

checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Another option for a multi select would be react-select.
React is a javascript software library and react-select is a component that makes the handling of selects in the application much easier.

Install package:

```
yarn add react-select
```

or

```
npm i --save react-select
```

This is an example for implementation:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Select 
    isMulti
    options={options}
  />
)
```

If you need more information, please visit: https://react-select.com/home